# PDF::loadView give me invalid format for numbers

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, pdf

I try to format number before download PDF file.

but i get invalid format number.

please check image to understand me.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title></title>
    </head>
  <body  style="font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif; font-size:10px;">
<header class="clearfix">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="https://socialworkers.org.sa/courses/storage/logo/7ZBqpaAd9TFla7922Wzl6kloSIGZoVl8PjkyRxfN.png"  style="float:left;margin-top:-30px;margin-left:20px; width:20%; height: 20%">
      </div>
      <div style="direction: rtl; margin-top:-20px;">
        <h2 class="name" style="text-align: right; margin-right: -70px;">{{$data['settings']->siteName}}</h2>
        <div style="text-align: right; margin-right: -75px;">{{$data['settings']->address}}</div>
        <div style="text-align: right;">{{$data['settings']->mobile.' '}}</div>
        <div style="text-align: right;"><a href="mailto:company@example.com">{{$data['settings']->email}}</a></div>
      </div>

    </header> 
    <hr>
```

[image]

Comment: can you show some code that you tried, how you format number?

Comment: sure, i edit the post please check it

Comment: I don't think all your code made it in. It only includes the `<header>`, and nothing there looks like it's formatting a number, just rendering existing data.

Comment: how render data?